# Set adapter on spinner but got empty list

Tags: android-fragments

After I tried to set adapter on spinner in the fragment and ran the app, everything was ok but the list in spinner is empty. After searching many case like my problem, I still could not figure out the reason. 
Any advice will be appreciated.

```
public class DrinkFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drink, container, false);

    mSpDrinkItem = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.sp_drink_list);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> drinkAd = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.drink_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    drinkAd.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpDrinkItem.setAdapter(drinkAd);

    mSpTemp = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.sp_temp_list);
    mBtnOrder = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_order);
    mTxvOrderedList = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txv_ordered_list);

    setListeners();
    return v;
}
```

Comment: What does your drink_item array look like?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it looks like:
<string-array name="drink_item">
        <item>珍珠奶茶</item>
        <item>波霸奶茶</item>
        <item>仙草凍奶茶</item>
        <item>檸檬汁</item>
    </string-array>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...  I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.  I wonder if the problem lies with your fragment_drink.xml file?

In any case, I put together a working example based on your data.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.spinnerfragmenttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

DrinkFragment:

```
package com.example.spinnerfragmenttest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class DrinkFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Spinner mSpDrinkItem;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drink, container, false);

        mSpDrinkItem = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.sp_drink_list);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> drinkAd = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.drink_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        drinkAd.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpDrinkItem.setAdapter(drinkAd);


        return v;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment android:name="com.example.spinnerfragmenttest.DrinkFragment"
              android:id="@+id/drink_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_drink.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/sp_drink_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="drink_item">
        <item>珍珠奶茶</item> 
        <item>波霸奶茶</item> 
        <item>仙草凍奶茶</item>
        <item>檸檬汁</item> 
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

This produces the following spinner (shown normal and in drop-down mode)

[image: Normal]

[image: Dropped Down]

Comment: Sure!  Please accept my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I create a new project using your code above, and it worked. ^^